# Http Post not executing to ASP.NET, but GET requests do

Tags: javascript, c#, http, angular, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make a post request in Angular2. For some reason I cant make POST request. I changed both the client and server to GET request and left everything else the same, and it works fine. So im wondering if i can to configure the header a different way to be able to make the POST request.

 **Update** 
So i managed to get it to execute, but now the location parameter is showing null

Client

```
search(latitude: any, longitude: any){
        let headers = new Headers(); 
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
        let body = JSON.stringify({ latitude, longitude });
        this.http.post('/api/SampleData/CurrentForecasts',body, { headers: headers })
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(
            data =>  this.Debug(data),
            err =>  console.log("Error: \n"+err),
            () => console.log('Get Complete')
        ); 
}
```

Server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace Weather.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SampleDataController : Controller
    {
        private static string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CurrentForecasts(string location)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(" https://api.forecast.io/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // HTTP GET
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("forecast/APIKEY/"+location);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var forecast = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return Content(forecast, "application/json");
                }
            }
            return Json(null); 
        }
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendRequest()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(" https://api.forecast.io/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // HTTP GET
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("forecast/APIKEY/37.8267,-122.423");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var forecast = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return Content(forecast, "application/json");
                }
            }
            return Json(null); 
        }
    }
}
```

Error
location [null]

Comment: What does your routing configuration look like for the server side?

Comment: [Route("api/[controller]")]

Comment: The GET request with the same code, except the POST parameters works. So i doubt its that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';


let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({
   headers: headers,           
   search: new URLSearchParams('location='+body)
});
this.http.post('/api/SampleData/CurrentForecasts', null, options)
```

---

**Edit:**
It would be better idea to create a `class` in your server:

```
public class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

And change your method signiture to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CurrentForecasts(Location location)
```

To post data from Angular2:

```
let location = { Latitude: latitude, Longitude: longitude }
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let body = JSON.stringify(location);
this.http.post('/api/SampleData/CurrentForecasts', body, headers)
```

Comment: How do i import RequestOptions and URLSearchParams?

Comment: Edited. See answer again

Comment: I get ""{\"latitude\":\"37.8267\",\"longitude\":\"-122.423\"}" [string] Any idea how to format it so i can just get the coordinates. Thanks again man! 
"

Comment: you mean you want` latitude` and `longitude `as decimals in your method?

Comment: Yeah as decimals or numbers. I mainly want to get rid of all these backslashes in my string.

Comment: I edited answer how to get them as decimal. Don't worry about backslashes. They are not in your string, it's just debugger's representation.

Comment: Yeah its showing up as null or 0. Guess ill have to do some string parsing.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Below code is a solution for AngularJS. For Angular2 have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39216520).

```
var param = {location: body}
var configObj = { headers: headers, params: param };
this.http.post('/api/SampleData/CurrentForecasts', null, configObj )
```

Comment: [ts] Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; params: { location: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'params' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.

Comment: Yeah, but location shows null. 
location
null [string]

Comment: Yeah on my server.

Comment: maybe `'application/json'` causes null. try excluding headers `var configObj = { params: param };`

Comment: Nope it does not. Still remains null

Comment: Sorry I misread some letters. this answer was for AngularJS.
See my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39216520) for Angular2

Answer (score 0):

`HttpGet` should not handle your post request. What you might need is to define a `RouteAttribute` on your Web API controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/SampleData")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CurrentForecasts(string location)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(" https://api.forecast.io/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // HTTP GET
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("forecast/APIKEY/"+location);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var forecast = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Content(forecast, "application/json");
        }
    }
    return Json("Failed");
```

Also, in on your client side you could just say:

```
    let headers = new Headers(); 
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    let body = latitude+','+longitude ; 

    this.http.post('/api/SampleData/',body, { headers: headers })
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
        data =>  this.Debug(data),
        err =>  console.log("Error: \n"+err),
        () => console.log('Get Complete')
    );
```

Returning `Json(null)` or something like `Json("Failed")` could cause the above error. Probably if you try to wrap your response into some object that has some `Success` property that is boolean so that you can query it on your side first before trying to read some `data` property. If you create a model or view model like:

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public IList<SomeModel> Data {get; set;}
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

And then create your response around the above model. You might want/need to elaborate on the above model a bit.

Comment: I already have a RouteAttribute. The null was just filler until i figured out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Default routing in .Net is going map actions to method names that are similar (coding by convention). The default GET action will find the first method available if nothing directly matches.

Since your controller is named "SampleData", you will either need to...

A) Rename your methods in a similar fashion, such as "GetSampleData", "PostSampleData" etc.

B) Add the data annotations for HttpPost and Action so that the router knows how to map things up such as

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("CurrentForecasts")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CurrentForecasts(string location)
{
   ...your code here
}
```

Just update your body so that the form fields match up and you should be set.

Comment: 'Action' is not an attribute class [netcoreapp1.0]
Action.Action(object @object, IntPtr method)

Comment: Apologies, should have read "ActionName" I've updated accordingly.

Comment: That gives me this error
Error: 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: It could be then that your Angular code isn't properly encoding the data to be sent to the endpoint. It may be helpful to use a tool such as PostMan to verify that the API is properly handling the endpoint and the data submitted to it, then verify that the client code is properly constructing the request and submitting it. You have two moving pieces to this. I suspect that the API routing issue is resolved, now it is just submitting the post request properly.

Comment: True, but the GET request is only going to check for data in the query string of the URL, using standard HTTP encoding, whereas the POST request is going to look into the request body, which is expecting properly formatted JSON, which the .Net parser appears to believe is not formatted correctly